# shiftOut using SPI isn't working

Tags: arduino-uno, shift-register

I made a sample using two of them using Arduino UNO.
So I did that like this:

[image: Arduino with 74HC595]
(There aren't any resistor on that image, but there are 220ohm resistor on every LEDs.)
And uploaded this code.

```
//1.6us+62.5ns
#include <SPI.h>

#define sbi(port, bit) (port) |= (1 << (bit))
#define cbi(port, bit) (port) &= ~(1 << (bit))

int latchPin = 12;
int clockPin = 13;
int dataPin = 11;

byte data[]={ 0b10101010,0b11001100 };

void _595_out() {
    cbi(PORTB, 4);
    SPI.transfer(data[0] );
    SPI.transfer( data[1] );
    sbi(PORTB, 4);
}

void setup() {
    pinMode(latchPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(dataPin, OUTPUT);

    SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV2);
    SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST);
    SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE0);
    SPI.begin();
}

void loop() {
    _595_out();
}
```

And this worked as I expected. But, when I changed sketch like this,

```
//1.6us+62.5ns
#include <SPI.h>

#define sbi(port, bit) (port) |= (1 << (bit))
#define cbi(port, bit) (port) &= ~(1 << (bit))
#define CHIPNO 2
int latchPin = 12;
int clockPin = 13;
int dataPin = 11;

byte data[]={ 0b10101010,0b11001100 };

void _595_out() {
    cbi(PORTB, 4);
    SPI.transfer(data[0]);
    SPI.transfer(data[1]);
    sbi(PORTB, 4);
}

void setup() {
    pinMode(latchPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(dataPin, OUTPUT);

    SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV2);
    SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST);
    SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE0);
    SPI.begin();
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    for(unsigned int z = 0; z < 65535; z++) {
        data[0] = z & 255;
        data[1] = (z & 65280) >> 8;
        Serial.println("A");
        Serial.print(data[0]);
        Serial.print("/");
        Serial.println(data[1]);
        Serial.println("B");
        _595_out();
        Serial.println("C");
        delay(500);
    }
}
```

74HC595s aren't working. Any LEDs aren't on.
Printing Serial works well. Only 74HC595s aren't working.
And Removing all Serial-related thing doesn't solved this problem.
Where did I do wrong?

Comment: Did you do a `Serial.begin()`? Please post the entire sketch that doesn't work.

Comment: *shiftOut using SPI isn't working* - *And this worked as I expected.* - so SPI is in fact working?

Comment: @NickGammon I just changed the loop function like that and added `Serial.begin(9600);` ath the end of the setup function. Everything except these is same as the first code, so that's why I didn't upload the entire sketch... And **shiftOut** using SPI is working when I use first code, but isn't working when I change the code as I said.

Comment: @NickGammon What I trying to do is changing outputs of 74HC595 every 0.5sec at very fast speed and that's why I'm using SPI. On first code, it's sending same outputs every loop, and it worked so I just changed that code to send different value every loop. But now it doesn't work. That's what it happened :-P

Comment: Why are you wanting to drive AY-3-8910 chips with shift registers...? It sounds like you are thinking of having one AY-3-8910 per shift register pair, which is just plain silly. Do some research about how these kind of chips interface to a CPU bus, which is what they are designed to do.

Comment: http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/AY38910 ?

Comment: @Majenko Umm...as I know, AY-3-8910 uses 8bit bus for input/output(see [this datasheet](http://dev-docs.atariforge.org/files/GI_AY-3-8910_Feb-1979.pdf) 36, 41, 43 page), and that's why I am thinking of having one AY-3-8910 per shift register pair. Can I get any information of that research? I'm just a noob to here and don't know about that :-(

Comment: The clue here is the word *bus*. All the AY-3-8910 chips can share the same bus. The only thing that needs to be unique is the equivalent of the address decoding (A8 and /A9 on the chip).

Comment: @MikaelPatel Yeah, but I am planning to control 10 of them, so I used 74HC595, just like [this](http://www.midibox.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=midibox_ay_3_8912_board). And that above thing is for testing and isn't working :-(

Comment: @Majenko Wait for a sec, I couldn't understand yet and got "shock and awe". Can you give me a detail?

Comment: An AY-3-8910 chip is only active when A8 is HIGH and A9 is LOW. By only having one chip active at a time all the other signals can be shared. That's 8 data signals, plus BDIR and CLOCK that are common. That's 10 pins for the bus, and a number of pins for selecting chips. That could be one pin attached to A8 and another attached to A9, which gives you 4 AY-3-8910 chips on 12 pins. Add a 2-to-4 decoder in place of the direct A9 connection and you get 8 chips off 13 pins. Change that to a 3-to-8 decoder and you get 16 chips off 14 pins. The Arduino can do that without needing any shift registers.

Comment: @Majenko The reason why I paired one shift register per AY-3-8910 is to control multiple chip with different data at one loop. And I'm trying to control AY using two pins, BC1 and BDIR, which are also controlled by another 74HC595 lane(not a paired shift registor lane), so I can control 10 AY-3-8910 using only 6 pins of Arduino. So maybe I can't use that way right now.

Comment: Anyway, I really want to solve this **shift out** problem because I want to use this on another project.

Comment: Where does  AY-3-8910 comes from in the comments? There is no mention of it in the question.

Comment: @NickGammon Actually it was, but i thought that isn't necessary on my question so i removed that. Sorry for the confusion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int latchPin = 12;
```

You use pin 12 as the latch pin. Once you activate SPI the hardware takes over control of the pins MOSI, MISO and SCK. Pin 12 is MISO and thus attempting to change it in your code will have no effect.

You should use some other pin as the latch pin (pin 10 is often used).

---

> And shiftOut using SPI is working when I use first code

`shiftOut` is a software-based method of clocking out bits. It doesn't use hardware and thus it doesn't take control of pin 12.

---

Note: Answered originally on [the Arduino Forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=448017.0)